# Detach SQL Server database without deleting it?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to detach a database without deleting it?

Comment: Can you describe more about why you would need to do this? You've got 3 decent answers that are all making different assumptions about what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Detaching a DB will remove it's entry from the internal list of DBs managed by Master but will leave the file there to re-attach.  This often could be perhaps not the best course of action to take but to do it follow the MS docs for [detach a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/detach-a-database).

You could execute the following but it could fail if users are connected to the database in your instance:

```
EXEC sp_detach_db 'Databasename', 'true';
```

You could always run a quick sp_who2 to see who is connected to your database or a [more thorough](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/indupriya/bidn-blog/553/determine-users-connected-to-sqlserver-database):

```
select spid, status, loginame, hostname, blocked, db_name(dbid), cmd from master..sysprocesses where db_name(dbid) = 'databasename'
```

As BradC has answered, taking a database 'offline' is also a good option which has it's own benefit and drawback.  Detaching unlocks the file so you could have the file manipulated while it it detached.  Just note having a database 'offline' can cause your scripts or maintenance tasks that scan all your databases to report failures.  It will still 'see' the database, try to access it, but it will not be able to.  Typically most maintenance scripts I write have logic to handle this but many in the wild do not so just note that.

Answer (score 4):

**Instead of detaching a database, its always a [wise decision to do backup](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups/) (and restore to a different server)**

Another option using PowerShell is to use dbatools - **[`Dismount-DbaDatabase`](https://dbatools.io/dismount-dbadatabase/)**

e.g. Below comand forcefully detaches (as a caution, I have used **-whatif** to not perform any action and just to print out what the command will do)

> Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance sql2016b -Database 'SomeUselessDB' | Detach-DbaDatabase **-Force** -whatif

If you have a detached db and you need more info on that, dbatools gets you covered using [`Get-DbaDetachedDatabaseInfo`](https://dbatools.io/functions/other/get-dbadetacheddatabaseinfo/)

> Get-DbaDetachedDatabaseInfo gathers the following information from detached database files: database name, SQL Server version (compatibility level), collation, and file structure. “Data files” and “Log file” report the structure of the data and log files as they were when the database was detached. “Database version” is the compatibility level.

Comment: Worth mentioning a `COPY_ONLY` backup to avoid differential database changes?  And perhaps link to the `BACKUP` command at the MS site.

Comment: I did not put copy only since if you are detaching the db .. you know that a full backup is what u will need incase things go wrong.

Comment: I meant use the COPY_ONLY option for the full backup to prevent the pages for a diff being reset. Its explicitly dicussed in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/copy-only-backups-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little vague, but if you are wanting to work with the database files on disk without SQL losing all the meta-data about the database, then what you want is to [take the database offline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-user-databases):

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET OFFLINE;
```

The database still shows in the server list, but can't be accessed until you bring it back online.

This statement may fail if there are active connections. To force it, use [`WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005662/how-to-force-a-sql-server-2008-database-to-go-offline):

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name  
SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Now move your files around, and make sure to tell SQL where to look for them:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name 
MODIFY FILE (NAME = logical_name, FILENAME = 'new_path\os_file_name');
```

Then bring it back online:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET ONLINE;
```